# how to make tablelayout with same width row, in one row contains two cell with same height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

How to make layout android for below picture? but I want each column has same width
[image]

I have created but it cannot be same width for each column

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#9812AC">        
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:text="Happy Vendor3">
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">        
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:text="Happy Vendor"
                android:background="#000">
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:text="Happy Vendor2"
                android:background="#CCC">
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just tried using textview to make it simple. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableRow 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/someimage1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".5"/>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".5">

<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/someimage2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".5"/>

<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/someimage3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".5"/>

</LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: it doesnt work, all imageview will be displayed like linear layout with vertical orientation

Comment: yes it works, could you also give me for autoresize imageview? note i use your layout

Comment: "autoresize imageview"? If you mean imageview expanding to fullest extent of the view it's android:scaleType="fitXY" OR android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```